# How to give multiple data as input in the same feature file in Specflow

Tags: c#, testing, bdd, specflow

I have a form in the application that needs to be filled with data like creating an employee.
Details like Employee code, name, address, bank details needs to be filled.
I have created a single feature file with 4 scenarios:

1. Employee personal details
2. Employee Address
3. Bank Details
4. Etc..

How do I pass data for 5-10 employees as the fields are the same? The problem is there are 15-20 fields that needs to be filled while creating. I tried with Example keyword and the row length increases, which makes it difficult to scroll and search. Is there another way that I can give them as input?
I doubt that we can give 4 example files for each of the scenario. Is that true?

Please help with a better way.

Here is a screenshot showing the Example text I was talking about:

[image: Specflow Example Image]

Comment: Are you able to include the scenarios in your question? I'm having trouble understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of including all fields in your examples table, focus on the fields relevant to the current scenario.

As an example, the scenario about personal details could look like:

```
Scenario Outline: Entering personal details when creating an employee
    Given the user is creating a new employee
    When the user enters the employee personal details:
        | Field         | Value           |
        | First Name    | <First Name>    |
        | Last Name     | <Last Name>     |
        | Date of Birth | <Date of Birth> |
    And the user enters the employee address
    And the user enters the employee banking details
    And the user saves the new employee
    Then ...

    Examples:
        | First Name | Last Name | Date of Birth |
        | ...        | ...       | ...           |
        | ...        | ...       | ...           |
        | ...        | ...       | ...           |
```

The step `When the user enters the employee personal details:` contains the fields relevant to entering personal details. The other steps about entering the employee address and banking details can use generic data, as long as the data entered satisfies the business rules.

Similarly, imagine the scenario about entering the address:

```
Scenario Outline: Entering new employee address
    Given the user is creating a new employee
    When the user enters the personal details for the new employee
    And the user enters the employee address:
        | Field       | Value         |
        | Line 1      | <Line 1>      |
        | Line 2      | <Line 2>      |
        | City        | <City>        |
        | State       | <State>       |
        | Postal Code | <Postal Code> |
    And the user enters the employee banking details
    And the user saves the new employee
    Then ...

    Examples:
        | Line 1 | Line 2 | City | State | Postal Code |
        | ...    | ...    | ...  | ...   | ...         |
        | ...    | ...    | ...  | ...   | ...         |
        | ...    | ...    | ...  | ...   | ...         |
```

This keeps the examples tables for each scenario smaller in size and easier to read, yet gives you lots of data input flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what is more important.

If being able to see the data that's being worked on beside the test is more important then you'll just have to bite the bullet and deal with the large amount of text in the test file.

If keeping your test file concise is more important, then you can create the data as a data type of some kind (e.g. List, Dictionary) and, on the first line in your tests, assign the data to a variable that you then use throughout the rest of your tests.